# Load css and/or jquery only on specific urls

Tags: jquery, css

I've got some css and jquery code which is normally loaded on every page of the website. However, it's not necessary for most of the code to load on the homepage, so the homepage becomes unnecessary slow. Is there a simple way to make the css and jquery script only load if a subdirectory is visited?

Edit: I'm using a website builder that allows users to add some custom css,html and jquery to the head tag of every page. Furthermore, the css is loaded when the site page loads, and jquery is only available after the page is loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just not load the scripts you don't want in the homepage ? Do you use some kind of framework that automatically load your css/js ?

Comment: Don't include the `<script src="unwanted.js"></script>` tag in the HTML of the homepage. Same with the `<link href="unwanted.css">` tag.

Comment: Also, please [do some preliminary searching first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Load+css+and%2For+jquery+only+on+specific+urls) before asking. [Google often does a better job](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Load+css+and/or+jquery+only+on+specific+urls).

Comment: @Benjamin I have a sense that user might be talking about some SPA framework or other async methods like AJAX to load content.

Comment: what is your backend language?

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the comments. As you might notice, I'm not an expert in this field. I use Sharetribe, which is a website builder dedicated to platforms. As far as I know, the programming language is Ruby on rails. Pardon me if I confuse stuff.